# passar uma variavel para uma url

Tags: javascript

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
var codigo = "abC";
});
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-default" href="/meuApp/pagina?codigo=" + codigo +  >Cancelar</a>
```

Boa tarde.

Estou quebrando a cabeça e não consigo passar uma variavel para uma url .

Está certo usar isso:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
var codigo = "abC";
});
```

E na pagina que tenho a url :

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="/meuApp/pagiba?codigo=" + codigo >Ver</a>
```

Nem abre minha página qd coloco isso. Oque estou errando?

Comment: Seu link está correto?

Comment: Sim... só não consigo pegar essa variavel.

Comment: ja tentou usar um "document.write(codigo)"?

Comment: @LucasTorres coloco na url ?

Comment: Primeiro de um inspect na página e veja se o codigo está sendo impresso, caso não, coloque uma tag script depois do igual e tente fazer isso. Apenas para teste

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não pode usar a variável desta forma no seu HTML, não vai ser interpretado o JavaScript dentro do seu elemento HTML.

Você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
<a class="btn btn-default custom-url" href="#" >Ver</a>

     $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.custom-url').attr('href', '/meuApp/pagiba?codigo=SEUCODIGO');
});
```